# How to update a jsonb column's all value to same one without specifying keys in postgresql?

Tags: postgresql

There is a value as following:

```
{"111": false, "222": false, "333": false}
```

How to update it to as following without specifying keys?

```
{"111": true, "222": true, "333": true}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can first decompose the JSON with `json_each()` giving you one key and value pair per row. Use a `CASE` to replace `false` with `true`. Then compose a JSON using string concatenation and `string_agg()` and cast it back to `json`.

```
UPDATE json
       SET json = (SELECT ('{'
                           || string_agg('"'
                                         || key
                                         || '": '
                                         || CASE
                                              WHEN value::text = 'false' THEN
                                                'true'
                                              ELSE
                                                value::text
                                            END,
                                            ', ')
                                         || '}')::json
                          FROM json_each(json));
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.4&fiddle=fe458ed205aba792964c1815a35f1954)

Or use the `jsonb` variants, if the type actually is `jsonb` rather than `json`.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use `REPLACE` on strings:

```
REPLACE(source, 'false', 'true')::jsonb;
```

where `source` is your `jsonb` column.

Comment: It is practical, but is not a smart way. By the way, your code will raise error. REPLACE(source::text, 'false', 'true')::jsonb

Comment: How is this not smart? Since you don't want to specify keys, to me it seems the smartest (if not the only) viable approach.